# Executing a page's JavaScript inside a WebView's JavascriptInterface in Kotlin

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview

As an example, let's assume for a project, I have a WebView instance I'm using in my main activity loading a local HTML file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var myWebView:WebView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true;
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/websrc/mainPage.html")
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "Android")
    }    
}
class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {
    @JavascriptInterface fun getStatus() {
      MainActivity().myWebView.evaluateJavascript("setStatus('good to go!')", null)
      //Or: MainActivity().myWebView.loadURL("javascript:setStatus('good to go!')")
    }
}
```

I have a JavascriptInterface also, where from I would like to invoke `Android.getStatus()` in my HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status"></div> 
  </body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        Android.getStatus()
    })
    function setStatus(status) {
      document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = status
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

So far, I *think* understand why this wouldn't work. From what I've come to understand from answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607657/webview-methods-on-same-thread-error) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446868/access-ui-from-javascript-on-android), And especially in the [documentation for WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript), I understand that the JavascriptInterface and the WebView are running on different threads, so something like `setStatus()` wouldn't be defined. So far, I've tried using `runOnUiThread` and `Handler()`. See an example for runOnUiThread:

```
@JavascriptInterface fun getStatus() {
      MainActivity().runOnUiThread(
                object : Runnable {
                    override fun run() {
                        MainActivity().myWebView.evaluateJavascript("setStatus('good to go!')", null)
                        //Or: MainActivity().myWebView.loadURL("javascript:setStatus('good to go!')")
                    }
                }
            )
    }
```

This (and use of Handler), however, gives me: `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaBridge` and `lateinit property myWebView has not been initialized`. I really don't understand why. Should mention I'm new to Kotlin and Android.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed was to pass `myWebView` to the JavaScript interface along with `this` and use `Runnable`...

Creating the JS interface:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this, myWebView), "Android")
```

And then inside a `@JavascriptInterface` function:

```
myWebView.post(Runnable {
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:customFunction()")
        })
```